# How to avoid downtime on AppDomain restart?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

IIS has a new (to me) extension called "Application Initialization".  One thing this does, among other things, is that when an application pool recycles, it will wait for the new site to be ready (by requesting the homepage [or another page]) before it switches to the new application pool.  This causes a user to experience no downtime because now it's not waiting for JIT-ing or database caching to happen on the first call.

This is all good, but it's only for AppPool recycles (such as when it has been running for ~29 hours).  When a DLL is copied to the bin directory, there is an AppDomain restart.  I'm wondering if there is anyway to avoid the downtime caused by this (other than taking the server out of rotation before deploying a change).

Comment: Whoever nominated this for reopening, can you please explain your reasoning? This appears to be very clearly off-topic.